# Error in salesforce

Tags: integration

https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Contact/updated/?start=2015-01-5T17%3A34%3A55.716Z&end=2015-01-15T19%3A21%3A03.904Z
gives error saying

[{"message":"Error parsing the 'start' date string. This operation requires properly formatted 'start' and 'end' date/time parameters to be specified. Please consult the documentation for the format of these date/time fields.","errorCode":"INVALID_DATE_FORMAT"}]
 I am using php for coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime variables in SOQL take the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ

That's a "T" between the date and the time and a "Z" at the end - this is a date/time in UTC timezone - and there are no milliseconds.

Date variables in SOQL take the format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Works the same in API calls as well.

Comment: Is there any rest uri to get the timestamp of the server?There is a SOAP call to get servertimestamp which on using i am getting the above 'end' value

Comment: Take a look at this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53525/how-to-get-the-server-timestamp-through-soql-query-or-rest-api